# Extend drive volume in HP 3 PAR storage

Tags: storage-spaces

I was running low disk space in my server which is using the storage from an HP 3 PAR storage. There are some unallocated space and i have created around 100 GB space to extend my volume. After restarting, the volume 100GB is displaying but can not extend to the drive which is running with low space. I am using a windows server OS and can someone help me on this ?

Comment: what error is showing when you trying to extend? sometimes a reboot is required

Comment: Rebooted; but seems no use